# How do I prevent water intrusion through the side of my garage door?

Tags: garage, sealing, garage-door, weather-resistant

Water is making its way past my garage door. I thought about the brush sweeps but how do they fare with keeping water out? The door is a corrugated rolling garage door. In central Texas we have the sideways rain so it gets into the spaces between the door and just goes right in.

[image]

Comment: Does the door manufacturer offer any sort of weather stripping for the edge of the door? I've got PVC + rubber weather stripping for my door, but it's a standard panel door, not a roll-up corrugated door, so mine probably wouldn't work for your door. I'd imagine you'll need something specific for this door type and the mfgr would be the first place I'd check.

Answer (score 1):

The door is not made to prevent water intrusion.

You will need to take measures to prevent damage from water when there is blowing rain.  However expecting there be no rain infiltrate the sides of the door is unrealistic.

Answer (score 0):

Flashing.

You can have custom flashing bent by a fabricator that would screw to the wall, extend around the track and to the back side of to door preventing water from entering through the side. Essentially an oversized *Z* metal.

You will however have to deal with it once it drains down to the floor which could be accomplished by a channel drain. Granted this will take some work to get installed and working properly but it would most definitely help solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a roll-up type of door.  It seems to me you could fabricate trapezoidal wedges (wood? rubber? foam?) that would fit in the gaps at the edges, and glue/screw them to the door.  They would fill the major voids that let water in, but you might need to adjust the weatherstripping on the outside to be tighter to the door, as it looks like there's a gap between it and the outside faces of the door's corrugations.